# AS3/Flex: Improving slow performance of drawing Application using BitmapData.draw()

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, performance, drawing, bitmapdata

I am using a custom Flex skin to create an active blur/frosted glass effect on the background of floating Panels, TitleWindows, and other containers (similar to http://www.pixelfumes.com/blog/apr07/activeBlurClass.html). There is a background image in the Application skin, and potentially any number of other components above and below the active blur component. Here's some relevant code within the skin:

```
public static const BLUR_FILTER :BlurFilter = new BlurFilter(16, 16, BitmapFilterQuality.HIGH);

private var _bitmapFill :BitmapFill = new BitmapFill;

private var _matrix :Matrix = new Matrix;

protected function handleEnterFrameEvent (event :Event) :void {

    var bitmapData :BitmapData,
        matrix :Matrix;

    // only run if component has width and height
    if (unscaledWidth && unscaledHeight) {
        bitmapData = new BitmapData(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight, false);
        // use the component's transform matrix to source the area to draw
        matrix = transform.concatenatedMatrix;
        _matrix.tx = -matrix.tx;
        _matrix.ty = -matrix.ty;
        // hide component to draw what's behind it
        visible = false;
        // this is the performance hit: draw the application to a bitmap
        bitmapData.draw(IBitmapDrawable(parentApplication), _matrix);
        visible = true;
        bitmapData.applyFilter(bitmapData, bitmapData.rect, new Point, BLUR_FILTER);
        _bitmapFill.source = bitmapData
        backgroundRect.fill = _bitmapFill;
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, the performance of this when the component is being resized, and especially when moved, is poor. There is noticeable drag delay and overall slowdown, and this is with only one popped-up TitleWindow in the test application. There is especially poor performance when components inside the TitleWindow are changed (button hover states, etc.)

I've attempted to optimized a little bit by avoiding reinstantiation of the blur filter, bitmap fill, and matrix, but this has had little or no effect. I removed the blur at one point, just drawing the Application to a bitmap, and the performance is still poor, so it's clear that it's mostly the BitmapData.draw() call.

I've read about using scrollRect and cacheAsBitmap, but I'm not sure where to apply these properties (or other optimizations I'm not aware of) within the Application or its components.

I've been at this problem for a while, and decided it was time to reach out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this one is really interesting..
did u test adding eventlisteners for say, layoutmanager for triggering redraw and
replacing blur filter with same pixelbender shader?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I've also tested it only on move/resize events, and tested removing the filter entirely. It seems to be just the BitmapData.draw() call that kills it. Perhaps understandably, since redrawing and rasterizing all the DisplayObjects in view is pretty expensive. I'm currently experimenting with writing a PixelBender shader blend mode to perform the effect.

Comment: I ended up writing the PixelBender shader, only to find out it can't be used properly as a blend mode with transparency. Oh well, Flex is dead now anyway. Good riddance!

Answer (score 1):

You should learn how to create proper Flex component using [Flex's lifecycle functions](http://blog.mediarain.com/2009/01/custom-component-lifecycle/).  Right now, you're drawing at every frame, which is extremely wasteful and useless.  Also, why do you need to draw the whole application over and over again?

You might want also look at a technique called [double buffering and bitmap blitting](http://jessewarden.com/2005/11/blitting-double-buffering-for-tile-based-games-in-flash-flex-part-1-of-3.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is within the skin, rather than the component. The rest of the skin is being drawn/styled with a combination of styleChanged(), invalidate/commitProperties(), and invalidate/updateDisplayList(). For this component, I need to draw whatever is behind it on each cycle. I understand that using enterFrame is wasteful for components that aren't moving, so I am only triggering this on resize/move for those. However, since some of these active blur windows may be displayed over moving content, they need to update frequently, hence the enterFrame listener.

Comment: As for drawing the whole Application, I would love to find a way to only draw whatever is behind the window/component that the active blur is being applied on, but I don't know how to do this. I'll read up on the link you provided, and thanks again.

Comment: JAX is correct use the resize even on the component to set the skin get this out of the enterframe event